# How to make Action blank in WCF service, as client need blank SoapAction=""?

Tags: wcf, soap, wsdl, svcutil.exe

I have a client they gave some WSDL, I generated some code from their WSDL using svcutil tool. `[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="")]` but it is not allowed in WCF. How I can make this Action a blank string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me: from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1ff173ee-c371-45b1-986b-fbb67ea94de8/wcf-integration-with-gsoap?forum=wcf)

Download the Microsoft WCF examples.
Add the following files to your project from WF_WCF_Samples\WCF\Extensibility\Interop\RouteByBody\CS\service

```
DispatchByBodyOperationSelector.cs
DispatchByBodyBehaviorAttribute.cs
```

Add the following attributes to your interface (next to your ServiceContract)

```
XmlSerializerFormat
DispatchByBodyBehavior
```

Add the following to your service interface

```
[OperationContract(Action = "")]
public void DoNothing()
{
}
```

For my service, the `WrapperName` and `Wrappernamespace` are null for all messages. I had to go into `DispatchByBodyBehaviorAttribute` and edit `ApplyDispatchBehavior()` to add the following lines to check for this:

```
if (qname.IsEmpty) {
    qname = new XmlQualifiedName(operationDescription.Messages[0].Body.Parts[0].Name, operationDescription.Messages[0].Body.Parts[0].Namespace);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer !!